# In python's smtplib why isn't the subject or From field set?

Tags: python, smtplib

can anyone see why the following code sends emails successfully but it shows up as being from the email address of the sender instead of the name of the sender in the recipients inbox, and the subject shows up as "No Subject" in their inbox. Thanks in advance.

```
def send_email(destination, subject, message):
    from_who = "My Name"
    to_send = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s""" % (from_who, destination, subject, message)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(my_email_addr, my_pwrd)
        server.sendmail(from_who, destination, message)
        server.close()
    except:
        print "failed"
```

Comment: You've got a "\" before `From`. Not sure if that breaks it, but it could.

Comment: In short, there are a few problems. Stray `\ ` and  `destination` should be sent as a list. Highly recommend the parsing method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `SMTP` in python, you need to send the data as a dictionary.

```
from email.parser import Parser

# This will parse out your to-, from-, and subject fields automatically
headers = Parser().parsestr(to_send)

# This will take care of the to- and from-fields for you 
server.send_message(headers)
```

---

> test.py

```
from email.parser import Parser

from_whom = "hello@example.com"
destination = "world@example.com"
subject = "Foobar!"
message = "Bar bar binks"

to_send = """From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s""" % (from_whom, destination, subject, message)

print(to_send)

headers = Parser().parsestr(to_send)

print(headers["To"]) # world@example.com
print(headers["From"]) # hello@example.com
print(headers["Subject"]) # Foobar!
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
to_send = string.join((
        "From: %s" % from_whom,
        "To: %s" % destination,
        "Subject: %s" % subject,
        "",
        message
        ), "\r\n")

# ...
server.sendmail(from_whom, [destination], to_send)
# ...
```

I think the other way is cleaner, but this is up to you.

Comment: Thanks but none of the examples I've seen of smtplib used this approach and they reported that it was working.

Comment: This is in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

Comment: You definitely need to have the message sent as a dictionary - that's how `SMTP` works.